# File exception when trying to save a word document

Tags: c#, ms-word, converters

Hi im developing a word add in that saves the document as html when requested. My code goes like that

```
Path = "c:/tmp/test.html";
var doc = globals.addin.application.ActiveDocument;
doc.SaveAs2(Path,WdSaveFormat.wdFormatFilteredHTML);
```

Now for some reason the save as throws a file exception ("a file exception has occcured")

And i really cant figure out why because it worked before, and if i try to do it from the word gui it also works

Comment: May be you should look in the inner exception? It could happen with security policies

Comment: Is the code in a try...catch block? With Office, that will sometimes return better error information. Beyond that, it sometimes helps to try the steps in VBA code, to see if it throws the same error. If it does, you know you're dealing with something that's not inherent in your VSTO/.NET code. If it does not occur in VBA, then you know you have to investigate how VSTO/.NET is doing things differently.

Comment: In .NET there is no "file exception". There is `IOException` or `FileNotFoundException` or (in the case of Office automation often also `COMException`). Could you clarify and tell us the exact type of the exception?

Comment: Hi. For some reason it just solved itself and i really have no clue what the hell it was. It was an io exception